# JavaScript: Why does appending query string with push/replaceState drop it on the next page?

Tags: javascript

I want to:

1. Append a query string without reloading the page
2. Have the query string pass to the next page without falling off
3. Avoid jQuery

So far I've found that pushState/replaceState fulfills #1 but it does not carry onto the next page (fails #2). What's strange is that my local tests with push/replaceState fulfills both #1 and #2 but in production the query strings fall off on the following pages.

For instance, I have a query string appended right when a user lands on the page.

```
window.location.href.indexOf('?') > -1 ? appendQuery('&') : appendQuery('?');
function appendQuery(queryMark){
if (history.replaceState) {
    var newurl = window.location.href + queryMark + 'QUERYSTRING';
    window.history.replaceState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}   
}
```

However, with this code the 'QUERYSTRING' does not stay appended when you navigate to another page within the site. How do I make the query string stay appended to the following page?

Comment: By next page do you mean an actual page navigation? How are you doing the navigation? You need to include the code you are working with preferably a [mcve]

Comment: Will edit for more clarification

Comment: @PatrickEvans actual page navigation.

Comment: And how do you achieve that? Anchor `<a>` tags? How do you set their href property? Note if you aren't doing it dynamically they won't pick up the querystring

Comment: @PatrickEvans the href property is passed dynamically. For example, once the user clicks on a button, the href is generated dynamically by the server based on the pre-existing query string the user comes with. I want to keep that pre-existing query string as well as append my own, which the user didn't have until page load. Everything works, except my query string falls once the href navigates the window to another page. I tried to avoid this portion as I thought it's irrelevant, but I'll be happy to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually making request to the server by calling `window.history.replaceState` or `window.history.pushState` (i.e you're only changing the state on the client side), which means that the server won't be able to serve you with the next page based on the url you're passing onto the replaceState/pushState methods.

What you want to do may perhaps be with window.location object? With `location.assign(newUrl)` or `location.replace(newUrl)`, you should be able to navigate to the new page while maintaining the query parameters since it actually makes request to the server.

PS: With client-side libraries like React or Vue, or frameworks like Angular, you can navigate to different pages with the use of history object because the navigation from one page to another is handled on the client-side without requesting the server. My answer based on the assumption that you're not using any client-side libraries/frameworks that handle navigation on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I'm curious then, if `window.history.replaceState` does not pass the query strings onto the server, what purpose does it serve? Unfortunately, I won't be able to use `location.replace(newUrl)` for my code in place of `pushState` or `replaceState` because that causes a flickering in IE/Edge which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: As I have said, many of the client-side libraries/frameworks today can handle navigation on the client-side without having to request the server. So history.replaceState/pushState is used to navigate from one page to another in such applications. Also, query params can be a mechanism to pass parameters to other pages while maintaining the state over a page reload. By keeping the state on the url, the state will not be wiped out even if the page is reloaded (unlike other client-side states).